# Did all people in Satyug use to get Moksha?

Tags: moksha, yuga

Since there was no sin in Satyug . Did all people use to get Moksha in Satyug ? Or Did all people would go to heaven ?

Comment: Sin and merit (punya) are both detrimental to Moksha .. if someone has no sins but lot of Punya even then he has to take birth repeatedly to enjoy the fruits of the Punya. So no Moksha for him despite having no sins.